# "Share Image" button for Android App

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, html, twitter

Lets say I have an Android html5 app with a picture generated with Javascript by passing a canvas to base64 and then appending it to DOM. I want to add some buttons to my app in order to share that image in, at least, Twitter and Facebook.

I've already seen how to trigger the "Intent" dialog with Java too. Is there any way to do that with Javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use PhoneGap?
If so, [try this](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/example-intents-phonegap).

You cannot trigger an Intent dialogue from a regular web page.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has an embedded `WebView`, you can use a javascript bridge to trigger the native share dialog.

The Android documentation has more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

I gave a talk on creating a javascript bridge. Here are the slides:
http://www.sqisland.com/talks/progressive-webview